# Jenkins FxCop errors should fail the build

Tags: c#, jenkins, report, fxcop, fxcopcmd

I have a **FxCop.project file** which i call using a Jenkins job

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0\FxCopCmd.exe" /project:"D:\Testing\Source\FxCop\BrokerApplication.FxCop" /out:"D:\Testing\Source\FxCop\BrokerApplication.xml"
```

What i want is to fail the job if there are any FxCop errors.

Is there anyway to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

After googling for hours I found a partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477933/parser-fxcop-results-xml-file-in-c-sharp) and decided to update it to an executable.

You can find my solution [here](https://github.com/anujalamahewa/fxcop-parser).

How to run it:

1. Checkout FxCopParser.exe (under release folder)
2. Pass the FxCop result xml file to it

   > "D:\Testing\Source\FxCop\FxCopParser.exe"
   >   "D:\Testing\Source\FxCop\BrokerApplication.xml"